# Kill Command Deleting Wrong File(s)i

Tags: vba, file, kill, delete-file

In Access VBA, I have a procedure I've put together to do this:

1. Allow the user to select zip file(s)
2. Extract any files from the zip files to the same directory (In this
   specific use-case instance, it is ALWAYS extracting Excel files from
   Zip files, never any change, and always using the same password)
3. Then I want the code to Delete the Zip file after extracting the
   .xls file.

Everything works beautifully except the delete file portion.  The issue is that when I tell it to delete "FileName.Zip", it is deleting "FileName.Zip" AND "FileName.xls"

Is there any way to make sure that he **kill** command ONLY deletes what I want it to delete?  I've used it before on various occasions, and never had this happen before.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim i As Variant

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblProjectPath")

Set fd = FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
fd.AllowMultiSelect = True
fd.Title = "Select TOC Return File(s) to process"
fd.InitialFileName = rs.Fields("ProjectPath") & "\FilingReports\*.zip"
fd.Show

For Each i In fd.SelectedItems
    'Debug.Print i
    Debug.Print '------------------------'
    Debug.Print i
    Unzip (i) 'The bit calling the command line unzip utility to unzip the file - just telling it to extract all files to the current folder.
    Debug.Print i
    'Kill i
    'had to take out the kill bit, b/c it was deleting both the .zip and .xls files which is not desired nor expected
    If InStr(i, ".zip") Then
        Kill i 'Tried to specify only .zip files even though think I shouldn't need to, but it's still deleting .xls files
    End If
Next i
```

Edit: Add Unzip code to post:
Unzip code:

```
Sub Unzip(Path As String)
    Dim strUnzip As String
    Dim QU As String 'quotation mark
    QU = Chr(34)

    strUnzip = QU & "c:\program files (x86)\winzip\wzunzip" & QU & " -s" & _
        "ZipPassword " & _
        Path & " " '& _

    Call Shell(strUnzip)

End Sub
```

Comment: Your 'If InStr(i, ".zip") Then' is incorrect... It should be 'If InStr(1, i, ".zip") Then'   Your code will ALWAYS be TRUE.

Comment: Actually, the code is correct.  the 1 is an optional value, which I did not need to specify, that according to the built-in help files.  But thank you for trying.  Just to be certain, I did try your suggestion but got the same result.  I eventually may just give up on the kill command and use the FileSystemObject instead.

Comment: What is the code in your 'Unzip' function? I just ran your code and it only deleted the one file (I manually unzipped the file). Try the following: (a) put a breakpoint on the 'Unzip'; (b) Run your code to the breakpoint, then manually unzip the file; (c) skip over your unzip statement; (d) run thru the 'Kill'; (e) check folder for wrong delete.

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah, I'll dig in on the Unzip code.  It basically just runs a command line call to wzunzip (WinZip's command line unzip utility).. I'll post it here in a moment..

Comment: Added Unzip code to the main post.  "Path" is the file path, pulled from the "i" variant variable which is pulling the file path from the FileDialog.

Comment: Just realized I never reported back on testing.  When I manually unzipped, it did not delete the Excel file.  Weird, but at least I know the culprit, it seems.

Comment: I created some zip files of Excel files and ran your code, but it works correctly. Only variation is I just hard-coded the directory instead of using a recordset value.  Afraid I am at a loss. Can't see a problem with the unzip code... let me try with a password (grasping...)

Answer (score 0):

At this point, I don't really think a "real" answer will come about.  However, I'll post what I've decided to do with the particular process I'm writing this code for anyway.

I'm going to use a folder structure to divide up the files:
1. Place zip file(s)
2. Unzip files to a 2nd folder
3. After processing Excel files in 2nd folder, move to a 3rd "complete" folder.

This will get around the deleting wrong files bit.

Also, it appears that the cause for the issue is related to something to do with the call to the WinZip Command Line Unzip utility (wzunzip) in the Unzip code above, or else something with the tool itself.  I thought that maybe it was b/c the tool was asking me if I wanted to overwrite existing files, but that wasn't the case, b/c I had the same issue when there were no files to overwrite.

Anyway, I'm attempting to close this one up at this point.  Thanks to Wayne G. Dunn for his assistance on this.